# Too many arguments for public open fun addValueEventListener(listener: ValueEventListener)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to connect my project with android App but I am facing this error.
My activity code is :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var my_view :MyView? = null
    private var seek_bar :SeekBar? = null
    private lateinit var mDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
    private lateinit var txtLabel : TextView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        txtLabel=findViewById(R.id.txtMotorLabel)
        initViews()
        var databaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        var myrefData = databaseReference2.database.getReference().child("/WaterLevel")
        myrefData.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener){

        }
    }
    private fun initViews() {

        my_view = findViewById(R.id.my_view)
        my_view!!.setProgress(75f)
    }
}
```

But the Error Comes:

> Too many arguments for public open fun addValueEventListener(listener: ValueEventListener): ValueEventListener defined in com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.

It should work like this:

```
ar myrefData = databaseReference.database.getReference()
        myrefData.addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
       // Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"READ DATA",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        var myrefData2=p0.getValue().toString()
        val arrofdevstatus: Array<String> = myrefData2.toCharArray().map { it.toString() }.toTypedArray()
        val devsM=arrofdevstatus[4]
        val devs1=arrofdevstatus[10]
        val devs2=arrofdevstatus[16]
        val devs3=arrofdevstatus[22]
        val devs4=arrofdevstatus[28]
```

Later on I can convert the received data to string or Array.

Comment: So did you solve the issue?